# Get Error while copy().

Tags: php

I'm trying to do `copy($src, $dst)` where `$src` is something like `'../folder1/folder2/file.ext'` and `$dst` is `'../new_folder/subfolder/newfile.ext'`. Note that `'../new_folder/subfolder/'` may not exist.

`copy()` throws the following error

> Warning: copy(../new_folder/subfolder/newfile.ext):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   scriptname.php on line 73

Where the problem is?

Comment: You have permissions to create it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the destination path is not getting properly. You need to provide the base path for the file along with the permission. Because some time folder level did not get recognized by writing the path like ../folder1/folder2

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion its got to be something to do with you path destination. But from recent experience in doing the samething i used file_get_contents, file_put_contents, and it worked a dream maybe copy has been deprecated.

https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents

https://www.php.net/file_get_contents

Follow these links on how they work but im sure they are more efficient (i think).

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The folder where you want to write the file needs to exist and you need to have write permissions for it.

"Copy" function needs both parameters to be ABSOLUTE PATH
Use realpath to get absolute path to a directory before making the copy.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#111833) comment, the folder where you are copying needs to exist first - which means you must do a check if the folder you want to copy to exists, and if it doesn't, to create it and the copy the file.

Make sure you have the appropriate permissions for the copying, and never, ever, set the permissions of the new file/folder to 777, unless you are absolutely sure you need this and you know what you are doing.